# Workflow Formula for Owner

Tags: workflow

I need to write a workflow formula that states if an owner is equal to a specific user with an action to check a specific box.  I tried doing with the simple criteria, but this is not working.  Does anyone know how this is done?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you activated the workflow? 
When you specify owner, are you specifying the ID or the name of the owner?

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Mark. Could you post the workflow rule you tried which didn't work for you? Knowing where you started from and the field names would be helpful to anyone who attempts to provide you with guidance. Just click on the Edit button at the bottom left to edit your post with the information.